# Could not load type Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Ok it is probably something simple but i just cant find where the problem is.
I have tried with but no match for my problem

I am trying to create from but from form class, not create form in controller..

here is the code..

this is from controller

```
    /**
 * @Route("login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction (Request $request) {
    $registration = new Registration();

    $form = $this->createForm(LoginForm::class, $registration, array(
        'method' => 'POST'
    ));

    return $this->render(
        'admin/login.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView())
    );
}
```

Inside controller i used USE to defind LoginForm i use in part createForm, so that is not problem

this is from FORM class

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\AppForm;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class LoginForm extends AbstractType {
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('password')
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
}
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(
        array(
          'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Registration'
        ));
}

public function getName()
{

}
}
```

Comment: And... What is your question? What are the errors?

Comment: in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry.php at line 83  -

                }
                if (!$type) {
                    throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Could not load type "%s"', $name));
                }
                $this->resolveAndAddType($type);

Comment: What version of Symfony you use? Check it accurately.

Comment: Could not load type "AppBundle\AppForm\LoginForm"

Comment: Symfony version 2.7.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem in Symfony version. You use code from Symfony3 while really have Symfony2.

Change `SubmitType::class` to `submit`, `LoginForm::class` to `new LoginForm()` and all will work fine.

Or you can update your Symfony version and all will work fine with your current code.

Comment: Yep.  The upgrade to S3 is going to be fun fun fun since all the existing links to the 'current' documentation will now point to incorrect S2.x information.

Comment: thank you, problem is solved, i am folowing Symfony documentation step by step so it's not my fault..

Comment: It is because Symfony 3.0.0 was released yesterday (http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-3-0-0-released). And now all documentation point to current (3.0) version. But you started your project some days ago and installed Symfony 2.7 instead.